# GUI development with c#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have a GUI that has a treeview on left side and a panel on the right side. The panel contains components like dropdown, radio buttons, textboxes,etc and I need to populate those according to the node selected on the tree.

Works fine till here. Howeer when I click on a button or any component on the panel, the node that was previously highlighted in the tree loses its focus. I mean that node does not remain highlighted any more. I want to keep that node highlighted when editing the components related to that node in the tree. How do I do that? Any help please?

Thanks.

Comment: I got it. I just put the 'hideselection' property to 'false'.

Comment: You should add this explaination  as an answer then come back in two days and accept the answer.

Comment: Good job, and thanks for posting the answer!

Comment: If JeffH's answer worked then you should accept his answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried setting the [TreeView's HideSelection property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.hideselection.aspx) to false?

Comment: Ya Jeff. Thats exactly what I did and it works fine now. Thanks anyways.